# Where can I find a large unprocessed dataset?

Tags: data-request, metadata, large-datasets

I am looking for a large dataset (greater than 100MB), preferably CSV, which is raw and unprocessed, with missing values. It is for a data preprocessing assignment as part of my college course on Big Data Analytics. I have to demonstrate data preprocessing in R or Python which I will work on. However, I am having a hard time finding a good dataset. On Kaggle, the datasets I looked at did not have missing values.

The dataset I have been considering is one from the New Zealand 2018 Census from https://www.stats.govt.nz/large-datasets/csv-files-for-download/. The one I have selected is the [Age and sex by ethnic group (grouped total responses), for census usually resident population counts, 2006, 2013, and 2018 Censuses (RC, TA, SA2, DHB)](https://www3.stats.govt.nz/2018census/Age-sex-by-ethnic-group-grouped-total-responses-census-usually-resident-population-counts-2006-2013-2018-Censuses-RC-TA-SA2-DHB.zip?_ga=2.218197209.1563931550.1663094489-2079092918.1662898429). It seems to be a good dataset for this purpose. It has around 34 million rows:
[image: Dataset Dimension]

However, the problem here is 18M out of those 34M records have a non-numeric value called "`..C`" for the `count` column which I'm not exactly sure what it means. I thought about considering them as "missing values" but that is more than 50% of the entire dataset:
[image: Dataset NA values]

Any help regarding finding a good dataset or further information on the above dataset would help!

Update: The above dataset seems to have a lot of outliers. So I would prefer a recommendation for a new dataset instead.

Comment: It seems odd that your instructor would make finding an appropriate dataset part of the assignment. It seems like a waste of the students' time without any educational benefit. Just sayin' ...

Answer (score 2):

[Japanese Trade Stats](https://www.kaggle.com/general/155805)
This seems to satisfy your request.
There are other data sets on that site if your find this particular one doesn’t.